# In objective-c how can i get the "url" and "content" between <a> tags using regular expression?

Tags: html, objective-c, regex

The `<a>` tag like this:

```
<a data-hash="9aab8aa3af7dc519c643fdcfd973b040" href="http://www.zhihu.com/people/9aab8aa3af7dc519c643fdcfd973b040" class="member_mention" data-editable="true" data-title="@somebody" data-tip="p$b$9aab8aa3af7dc519c643fdcfd973b040">@somebody</a>
```

and I want get the url

```
href="http://www.zhihu.com/people/9aab8aa3af7dc519c643fdcfd973b040"
```

and the `@somebody` at the same time

I have tried like this:

```
href=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)</a>
```

The result is:

```
href="http://www.zhihu.com/people/9aab8aa3af7dc519c643fdcfd973b040" class="member_mention" data-editable="true" data-title="@somebody" data-tip="p$b$9aab8aa3af7dc519c643fdcfd973b040">@somebody</a>
```

Is anyone can give me some suggestion?

Comment: Why use regular expression? Do some basic string processing/searching

Comment: Because I want learn more in regular expression, this is really useful. Thanks for your editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to match the extra parameters present inside the anchor tag.

```
"<a\\b[^>]*\\bhref=\"(.*?)\"[^>]*>(.*?)</a>"
```

or

```
"<a\\b[^>]*\\bhref=\"([^"]*)\"[^>]*>(.*?)</a>"
```

Then get the strings you want from group index 1 and 2. Your regex matches all the following chars (*ie, chars next to href attribute*) because it looks for an `>` symbol just after to the double quotes. Hence it finds a match in `data-tip="p$b$9aab8aa3af7dc519c643fdcfd973b040">`, so this part also get captured by the first capturing group.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wT0iY3/1)

Comment: Thanks body. you help me out. by the way "[^>]"this means not include?

Comment: `[^>]*` matches any character but not of `>` symbol, zero or more times.